# How to begin a package (newbie style)

Tags: programming

I am kinda new in LaTeX, but I'm trying to make a "package" to display abstract *structs* algorithms in `beamer`.

Ex: `\binarytree[]{a->b.c, c->e.f}` and my plan is to make this visual algorithm to `beamer`. Any advices or tutorials are welcome, and the major question, is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Honest advice: don't. Creating non-trivial commands with LaTeX can (will?) hurt your brain. Use LaTeX a lot and get familiar with its internals before attempting to build a package. For your problem, use TikZ (maybe with qtree) or graphviz.

Answer (score 2):

As a language, TeX is a very special beast because it is based on macro expansion instead of the procedural paradigm found in many other languages.  If you know M4 and C, TeX is much closer from M4 than from C.

Writing a macro performing some kind of lexical analysis, as you are seemingly trying to, is especially hard—yet perfectly feasible.

Instead of solving your problem within LaTeX, you can use your favourite language to write a program that will prepare one or more LaTeX source files containing your figures that you can `input` in your main document.